# What is this line getting from a different file (TCL)?

Tags: tcl

I am including the relevant code below, and I can explain what I know it is doing up to this point:

```
proc rshm {where {i 0}} {
    global ob
    set what "???"
    set ob(last_rshm_failed) "yes"
    if {![info exists ob(shm)]} {
        return "0.0"
    }
    if {[info exists ob(shm_puts_exist_in_progress)]} {
        return "0.0"
    }
    shm_puts "g $where $i"
    gets $ob(shm) istr
    set what [lindex $istr 0]
    set ob(last_rshm_failed) "no"
    if {[string equal $what "?"]} {
        set ob(last_rshm_failed) "yes"
        puts stderr $istr
        return "0.0"
    }
    set what [lindex $istr 3]
    return $what
}
```

From looking at the rest of the program, I have concluded that the first two if statements are checking for errors elsewhere and are designed to terminate the procedure if the errors trigger.

Elsewhere in the program, the place (of interest) that the function gets called is in the form:   rshm ft_xdev

Using print statements, I found that ft_xdev passes into the procedure as shm_puts "g ft_xdev 0".

The line that is throwing me off is the line:    gets $ob(shm) istr

The call to $ob(shm) is another file (originally a binary program, but the readable version is in C...), but upon looking at this file, there is no reference to anything called "istr".

Would someone mind helping me out with what this line is getting from the other file? If needed, I can provide more code from the program.

Comment: Don't spam tags! There is nothing C-related in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The code:

```
gets $ob(shm) istr
```

will pass the contents of the `ob(shm)` variable (which should be a channel handle that is at least open for reading) and the string `istr` (which is used to name a variable in this case) into the `gets` command. The `istr` will be a local variable in this case because it hasn't been explicitly stated to be otherwise.

The `gets` command, when given two arguments, will read a line of text from the channel (first arg) and write that line of text to the variable (second arg). It then yields as result the number of characters read *or* `-1` if there was a recoverable error condition such as end-of-file. You're ignoring the result. (Critical errors would become exceptions.) This is all documented on [the manual page for `gets`](http://tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/gets.htm).

**tl;dr:** Reads a line of text from the `$ob(shm)` channel and stores it in `istr`.

Comment: Unlike the `gets()` call in C, Tcl's `gets` command knows how to do memory management so that it can't suffer from a buffer overrun. When non-blocking IO is enabled, you've got more options for tacking the issues in this area. However, the pattern of code for doing so is a bit different; I bet you're not using non-blocking IO…

Comment: Thanks for the help! Earlier in the program, `ob(shm)` was defined as opening a file named shm (which stands for "shared memory") for reading. However, the file has a lot of code in it (more than just a few lines), so I guess I am confused what the procedure is storing in `istr`. Or maybe it is storing the entire script in the variable? At which point, what is the list that the next line is indexing?

Comment: @rkepp12, you'll have to figure out all the places where the program is reading from ob(shm). I'd be curious about what `shm_puts` does.

Answer (score 0):

This procedure will return the 3rd index of `$istr` (`[lindex $istr 3]`) if its not empty or does not fail on the prior checks.

**The contents of `$istr` are obtained from grabbing the next line of the open file channel `$ob(shm)` (if the channel is already open and `$ob(shm_puts_exist_in_progress)` does not exist).**

If `shm_puts "g $where $i"` impacts the $ob in any way, it would be important to include the procedure `shm_puts` since it may impact `$istr`, but I suspect the contents of `shm_puts` are not relevant to `$istr`.

Finally if `$istr` starts with a ? then it aborts this procedure displaying the contents of `$istr` to stderr. That is, if a line of the file starts with ?, then the procedure aborts.

All procedure aborts (ie IF checks) do not retain the contents of `$istr`, since its a local variable not a global one, so checking the contents of $istr must be done within this procedure and after the gets command.